# mb_substr as a solution for � works sometimes

Tags: php

Hihi,

I used to get the symbol � at the end of a string which ended with special character...

I found the solution by adding mb_ to the "substr" which become (mb_substr)

It worked but every now and then it still appears and vanish in some cases if I refresh.

It there a permanently fix for this bug?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is UTF-8 vs ASCII.

MB ("multi-byte") isn't really a solution.

"mb_detect_encoding()", and/or utf8_encode()/utf8_decode might get you a bit further:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php

Please read the info in this link.  If you're not already familiar with PHP "internationalization", it might be VERY useful to you:

http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8

Comment: thanx for this reference - Im gonna check them out and keep you updated